# how to clean large postgresql table contains many useless records?

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a quite large `log` table in my postgresql database(over 100 million records),  and many of the records are useless that I am gonna to clean to improve the IO performance.
and this work have to be done while the production db in service.

I have 2 ideas of myself:

## solution 1

- create a new table `log_new`
- rename tables in a transaction: `log` -> `log_old`, `log_new` to `log`
- clean the useless records from `log_old`, then move the remained records into the new `log`
- done

## solusion 2

- create a new table `log_temp`
- rename tables in a transaction: `log` -> `log_old`, `log_temp` -> `log`
- clean the useless records from `log_old`
- do `vacuum full` and `reindex` on `log_old`
- rename back the tables: `log` -> `log_temp`, `log_old` -> `log`
- move the records in `log_temp` to `log`
- done

---

> a short time log records missing is acceptable, but log writing can not be interrupted(table name reference from applications NOT changed, log writing request NOT be blocked).

question 1: do you see any **pitfalls** in my solutions ?
question 2: what would be your choice, or do you have a better solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I would:

1. Create a new table `log_temp`.
2. Insert into the new table all the records I want to keep.
3. Truncate the old table.
4. Insert the records from `log_temp` into the old table.

Truncating the table should be the fastest way to remove all the old records -- and it doesn't require any vacuuming.  The key is saving the right data in `log_temp`.  And verifying it before truncating the original table.

This method is also trigger-safe and works with many constraints.  That is, you don't have to redefine triggers if there were any on the original table.

Comment: but david want to keep some old records

Comment: @P.JAYASRI . . . The records to keep are in `log_temp`.

Comment: if he have to access old records(except useless records) from log table how can he achieve this ? i am new programming. this is my logical question only . if any thing wrong forgive me . then he can't access two table for same purpose

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you, log records are inserting to the `log` table every moment, how can I prevent truncate records that not have been backuped ?